# Jmeter - Regex Extractor not working

Tags: regex, jmeter

I'm trying to extract a simple string from the HTML response.
The response looks like this

```
patients-list-of-visits.aspx?p=a1363839-76fb-43f3-97ba-26218faefee1
```

The Regex I have tried so far are

```
patients-list-of-visits.aspx?p=(.+?)
patients-list-of-visits.aspx?p=(.+)
```

Can someone please let me know what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is better:

```
patients-list-of-visits\.aspx\?p=(.+)
```

2 remarks

- don't forget to escape . and ? if you want to match them literally
- your first attempt `.*?` is a lazy match and will result in in only the first letter being matched. Your second attempt is better